# Jinja template for loop with if statement

Tags: python, jinja2

I thought it would be possible to do the following (passing an unpacked dictionary `**my_dict`, where `{dict_key21: True}`):

```
{% for n in range(my_dict_len): %}
    <td>${dict_key1{{ n }}}</td>
    {% if dict_key2{{ n }} %}
        <td>New cell</td>
    {% else %}
        # Do nothing
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I get a `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError`:

```
{% if a_dict{{ n }} %}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 497, in _parse
    return Parser(self, source, name, encode_filename(filename)).parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 901, in parse
    result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 883, in subparse
    rv = self.parse_statement()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
    return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 199, in parse_for
    body = self.parse_statements(('name:endfor', 'name:else'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements
    result = self.subparse(end_tokens)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 883, in subparse
    rv = self.parse_statement()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
    return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 213, in parse_if
    'name:endif'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 164, in parse_statements
    self.stream.expect('block_end')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/lexer.py", line 384, in expect
    self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '{'
```

I've also tried different formats and using `set`:

```
{% if ${dict_key2{{ n }}} %}
```

---

```
{% if dict_key2{{ n }} == True %}
```

---

```
{% set is_true = dict_key2{{ n }} %}
{% if is_true %}
```

But they result in a similar `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError`

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: The exception is a syntax error. I don't think jinja2 allows you to use an expression `{{ ... }}` inside a statement `{% ... %}`. What are you trying to accomplish with `dict_key2{{ n }}`? What is `dict_key2` in this context?

Comment: @jonchar I'm trying to build a table with buttons, if the value for the key `dict_key2{{ n }}` is `True` then that row should have a button, and no button if it's `False`. `my_dict` is of varying length so I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: Can you give the simplest example of what `my_dict` looks like?

Comment: Sure @DylanMoore - `my_dict = {'dict_key11': 'Title', 'dict_key21': True}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `${dict_key1{{ n }}}` is invalid Jinja. Typically to [access a key in a dictionary in jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#variables) you would do something like `{{ dictionary.field }}` or `{{ dictionary[field] }}`.

Based off the example of:

```py
my_dict = {'dict_key11': 'Title', 'dict_key21': True}
```

A possible solution is:

```
{% set dict_length = my_dict|count-1 %}
{% for _ in range(dict_length) %}
  <td>{{ my_dict['dict_key1'~loop.index] }}</td>
  {% if my_dict['dict_key2'~loop.index] %}
      <td>New cell</td>
  {% else %}
      {# Do nothing #}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the above example we're using the [string concat operator](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#other-operators) `~` to join the key with the required number using a [special loop index variable](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for). `loop.index` was chosen because it starts at index 1. Something like `range(1, my_dict|count)` should also work.

Comment: Excellent, this is just what I was looking for. Although one note, I'm using `${dict_key1{{ n }}}` inside the for loop without issues, so I don't think it's invalid. What it doesn't like is using that variable inside of a if statement. Thanks Dylan!